# Specified method for NDSolve needed

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

*Dear friends*. Can anybody suggest me, if there exists a method of ODE solving by the funtion **NDSolve** similar to Maple's method in **dsolve** with use of **'output'=array** option? The latter allows one to obtain approximate solution in specified points (say, {0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0} for the domain [0,1]) + corresponding derivatives in these points by Richardson extrapolation scheme?

Comment: `NDSolve[]` actually does you one better; it produces a function defined over your domain of interest that can then be evaluated for any arbitrary argument within the domain. This function can also be differentiated if need be.

Comment: @J.M. Though I suppose you can create an array from `NDSolve[]` with `Table[]`, and then `Interpolation[]` it again. :/

Comment: Certainly, I'm familiar with features of **NDSolve**, but for my purposes I need something like Maple **dsolve** with array.

Comment: So like... `s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 1, 30}];`,  `Table[y[i] /. s, {i, 1, 30}]`

Comment: In fact, since the resulting function is listable: `s = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 1, 30}]; s[Range[1, 30]]`.

Comment: Thank you. 
Does  **NDSolve** always return **InterpolatingFunction**?

Comment: Barring serious errors, yes.